# login page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

hii i am new to web site development 
   there is a login page in my web site which is in ASP.net(C#.net) . After entering the username and password and user click on the Login button . The user name and password got check and it shows the message at the "the user name and password did'nt match" but i want this messageas a message box. Currently it is showing as a line on the left-top corner  of the page.. 
  if possible so please give the code

Answer (score 1):

You would have to put code in the LoginFailed event handler for the login control (if you are using the .NET framework login control, if not, proceed below).  The login control's template also has an error label that you would have to inspect the control's children for to hide since you don't want that to display.  In LoginFailed, or if you have your own UI login form, you can write out a message to display via:

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this, "error", "alert('The user name and password could not be verified');");

Answer (score 0):

You will have to draw your own message box using HTML formatting (maybe a formatted div element), or use javascript's alert box to do so if you're shooting for a quick solution.

```
alert('Error','The Username and Password didn\'t match.');
```

ASP.net outputs HTML to the browser, so if you don't have formatting then the message will simply appear unformatted on the page.

Comment: That wouldn't work too well in javascript, try escaping the apostrophe on "didn't" or use double quotes.